# Decorator Design Pattern in Cinema Ticketing System

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I wanted to apply the decorator design pattern for my cinema ticketing system. I noticed how different hall types (e.g. Regular, Luxe, Deluxe) had different prices. So, I made this simple decorator diagram.

[image: Decorator Design Pattern for Cinema Ticketing System]

I wanted to ask if I used the decorator pattern correctly in my case. If I want to add new hall types, I can just make a new class and use it right away.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: For `HallDecorator` to decorate `Hall` there needs to be a relationship between them, specifically, composition.

Comment: @jaco0646 You are right, completely forgot to add that. Thank you